# How do I allow python (pycharm in particular) to accept incoming SSL certificates?

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

Before I begin here is my code in Python, for which I am trying to download an image from the web (I am just getting use to Python, not for any specific reason).

```
import random
import urllib.request

def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + '.jpg'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)

download_web_image('https://www.thenewboston.com/photos/users/2/resized/a403d4e7fb26d7373009c97d68b2448b.jpg')
```

However when I run the code this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1240, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1083, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 911, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1237, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 376, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jake/PycharmProjects/BuckyTutorials/download image.py", line 9, in <module>
    download_web_image('https://www.thenewboston.com/photos/users/2/resized/a403d4e7fb26d7373009c97d68b2448b.jpg')
  File "/Users/jake/PycharmProjects/BuckyTutorials/download image.py", line 7, in download_web_image
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 187, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 483, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1283, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1242, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)>
```

This happens in both IDLE and pycharm. What am I doing wrong?